# Angular 5: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at scripts.bundle.js

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 5, I include my sample.js file below:

```
"use strict";
function abc() {
  console.log("hello from js");
}
module.exports = {
  abc: abc
};
```

Angular builds successfully. I can view my app at http://localhost:4200 and see 'hello from js' in the browser console. However, the browser console also shows this error:  "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at scripts.bundle.js:18" which points to the keyword 'module' in my sample.js. Why there is an error but the app can still run fine? Is this error bad?

Comment: can you add where you are using it?
also `module.exports` is `nodejs` styled syntax

Comment: If you are loading this file in browser then you need to use something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/) to convert it into browser supported code. it throws error because exports doesn't exist in browser only in node.